# Не загружается большое изображение в Firefox

Tags: изображения, firefox

Изображение http://ecg.html.brightstudio.ru/templates/ecg/img/animate/sawguy_515.png

Ширина изображения 101970 px — это спрайт с кадрами анимации.

Предполагается его использование в background-image + css3 animation. (Целевая страница, где используется анимация ecg.html.brightstudio.ru/1_main.php)

В IE, Chrome, Safari изображение загружается и отображается нормально. В FF отображается ошибка:

> "Изображение «http://ecg.html.brightstudio.ru/templates/ecg/img/animate/sawguy_515.png»
>   не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки."

Версия FF 42.0 на Ubuntu/Windows

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox не открывает изображения шире чем 32766 пикселей
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973667